# A Way to deal with this input?

Tags: c, input, getchar

I'm trying to identify a way in which when data is input like such:

```
Name Integer
Name Integer
Name Integer
.
```

Each time the Name and Integer are entered, and a newline is detected, *stuff* is done with that name and integer, then again, and again, until the '.' is detected.

I've tried `getchar()` loops, and IF statements to detect `'\n'` for example, but none seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you try to use scanf("%d\n", &myvar)?

Comment: Could you post some of your attempts, and why they don't work?

Comment: Or a combination of `fgets` and `sscanf`?

Answer (score 1):

What about using `scanf()`?

`scanf("%s %d\n", my_string, &my_int);`

http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%s%d\n", name, &intVar);
if((*name=='.') && (*(name+1)=='\0')){
return 0;
}
```

this should be suffice

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char input[30];
    gets(input);
    while(strcmp(input, ".") != 0)
    {
        // do stuff
        gets(input);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `scanf` directly. It's surprisingly hard to use. It's better to read an entire line of input (for example, with `fgets`) and to then parse it (possibly with `sscanf`).